# unable to send ckeditor data using Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea which using ckeditor

```
<textarea rows="25" cols="50" id="content" name="content" required="required"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
</script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
```

When i click to submit, A Jquery function called

```
$("body").on("click", "input.submit", function() {
        for(instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        }
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
        var dataString = 'content='+ content;
        if(content==='') {
            alert("Please fill all fields");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "transfer/action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    $(".error").html(result);
                },


    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                $(".error").html(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});
```

i inputted some data like....

> That's because there are question-and-answer sites like
>   where any developer can post a programming-related
>   question

When i clicked on submit button the data is showing in jquery but ajax is not sending data to php properly due to single quote where single quote is already encoded by editor.. Ajax denies to send data with single quote why..
please help me

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Ajax denies to send data with single quote"? Are you getting an error in your console? If so, what is it? Also, POST it again and check your "Network" tab in the dev tools of your browser and see what the POST headers are.

Comment: For example i inputted this data "That's because there are question-and".. ckeditor converted into html format "That&#39;s because there are question-and".. when i submitted and ajax called, i am getting only "That" on server side.. all other lost why? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable encoding of HTML entities on Ckeditor. Then, once you POST your data, you should be good. See more info here...

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Trying-disable-html-entities-not-working